# Xamarin Compile for iOS 5/6 + using XCode 5 and Xamarin 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, uiappearance

I have installed XCode 5 and supporting new Xamarin Studio etc.

I have legacy apps designed for iOS5/6 that I have to maintain as is with respect to UIAppearance/MT.Dialog etc. Is there a XCode5/Xamarin.iOS option that lets me compile the "old way" so that the apps looks and feel like a iOS5/6 app regardless of device?

When I run the apps on the Simulator 7, it trys to morph the UINavigation bars, UIAppearance etc to iOS7. I want it to look like an iOS 5/6 app regardless of the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution.

Install XCode 4.63 into a new folder in ~/Applications.

Change the Apple SDK in Xamarin Preferences to that location

Build and you'll get the old style so you can maintain old apps until ready to migrate them